# How do I erase the type of future in the new future API?

Tags: async-await, rust, future

[The following does not compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3725356ddcc70c5abcb5e3370392a136)

```
#![feature(await_macro, async_await, futures_api)]
use core::future::Future;

async fn foo() {}

trait Bar {
    type Output: Future<Output = ()>;
    fn bar(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl Bar for () {
    type Output = Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>;
    fn bar(&self) -> Self::Output {
        Box::new(foo())
    }
}

async fn buz() {
    await!(().bar())
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(dyn std::future::Future<Output=()> + 'static): std::marker::Unpin` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:19:15
   |
19 |     await!(().bar())
   |               ^^^ the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `(dyn std::future::Future<Output=()> + 'static)`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::future::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::future::Future<Output=()> + 'static)>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn std::future::Future<Output=()>: std::marker::Unpin` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:19:5
   |
19 |     await!(().bar())
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `dyn std::future::Future<Output=()>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::future::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::future::Future<Output=()>>`
   = note: required by `std::future::poll_with_tls_waker`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

How can I set the type `Output`? I want `bar` to return some `Future` by calling `foo` so I can `await!` in `buz`.

In the old days with `Future<Item = (), Error = ()>`, the above would compile without any problems as we don't have the `Unpin` constraint, but we also don't have `await`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the `Box` in a `Pin`:

```
impl Bar for () {
    type Output = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>;
    fn bar(&self) -> Self::Output {
        Box::pin(foo())
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sure I were tried this before but it does not work... But now it does. Thanks anyways.