# Is there a way that we can convert from futures 0.1 to the standard library futures?

Tags: rust, future

The `async`/`await` feature is coming soon, but there are a lot of libraries still using futures 0.1. How do we convert between the two?

[Convert an async future to 0.1 future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785707/convert-an-async-future-to-0-1-future) covers converting an async future to 0.1 future.

[How do I erase the type of future in the new future API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452339/how-do-i-erase-the-type-of-future-in-the-new-future-api) talks about an `async` function that calls an 0.1 future and gets the result, but where is the `await!()` macro I can import? It seems it no longer compiles.

```
struct A_future01;

impl A_future01 {
    pub fn exec1() -> Box<dyn Future<Item=String, Error=()>> {
        Box::new(futures::future::result("ok"))
    }

    pub fn exec2() -> Box<dyn Future<Item=String, Error=()>> {
        Box::new(call().unit_error().boxed().compat()) //Like this## Heading ##?
    }
}

async fn call() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let result_from_a = A_future01::exec().await(); //how can I achieve this ?
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Future01CompatExt` trait:

```
use futures01::future as future01;
use futures03::compat::Future01CompatExt;

fn make_future_01() -> impl future01::Future<Item = i32, Error = ()> {
    future01::ok(2)
}

async fn example_03_uses_01() -> Result<i32, ()> {
    let v = make_future_01().compat().await?;
    Ok(v)
}
```

```
[dependencies]
futures03 = { package = "futures", version = "0.3", features = ["compat"] }
futures01 = { package = "futures", version = "0.1" }
```